# python code completion in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, pymacs

I tried make PythonIDE using emacs like in this article http://www.enigmacurry.com/2009/01/21/autocompleteel-python-code-completion-in-emacs/ But emacs said me "auto-complete-mode not enabled". It is possible use emacs for python coding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to activate the auto-complete mode in the context where you get that message, either

- every time you open python files, by adding the following to your `.emacs`:

  ```
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
           (auto-complete-mode 1)))
  ```
- or when you open *any* file, by adding the following to your `.emacs`:

  ```
  (global-auto-complete-mode t)
  ```

The question you're linking to suggests something even more complete (i.e. which subsumes the first of the two additions I suggest):

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
             (auto-complete-mode 1)
             (set (make-local-variable 'ac-sources)
                  (append ac-sources '(ac-source-rope) '(ac-source-yasnippet)))
             (set (make-local-variable 'ac-find-function) 'ac-python-find)
             (set (make-local-variable 'ac-candidate-function) 'ac-python-candidate)
             (set (make-local-variable 'ac-auto-start) nil)))
```

Those additions will be needed to get full completion using snippets and [Rope](http://rope.sourceforge.net/).